# Android pie 9 music stop when minimize

Tags: 9.0-pie

I am using android mobile having android pie 9. When I play music and minimize app, it stop music. Even when I am use other option music stop playing. I want that music play in background when I use mobile.

Comment: Which app are you using?

Comment: It is default app on android pie 9 on nokia 2.2. It can play mp4. When I tap on music file it use file apps.

Answer (score 1):

As per the question, it doesn't look like the phone's default music player supports background play feature. You can use third-party apps like VLC Media Player to play music in the background (when minimized).

Comment: Yes it works with vlc player. But I want to know is there is setting for background music play on default player on android pie 9.